# Detect onClickListener or onLongClickListener on RecyclerView

Tags: android

I'm trying to detect from my mainActivity wheter the user does a normal click or a long press because depend of it I need to do one thing or another, and I have the object of my SQLite on my MainActivity and not in my Adapter, I do not know if it's better to detect it on the Adapter or in MainActivity.

My adapter is a normal one which has a ViewHolder and items on it, but I need to detect the click on the view not on an specific view on row, can you guide me how to?

I'd like to get like a callback that detects when user does one action and depends of it do one thing or another

### EXPLANATION

On my main activity I have the `private DatabaseHelper db;` object so I'd like to do something like if he does onClick view the detail onLongClick show a dialog to delete it.

Hope you understand my issue.

Comment: "Hope you understand", seems like you know your question is unclear, moreover cause you create an "explanation" section. So improve it to make it clearer. Could you provide your adapter and main activity ? What do you mean by "normal adapter" ?

Comment: This link has the exact material what you are looking for. Please follow the instructions. https://medium.com/@harivigneshjayapalan/android-recyclerview-implementing-single-item-click-and-long-press-part-ii-b43ef8cb6ad8

Comment: @DäñishShärmà Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use an interface for that purpose, like such:

**Add this to your Custom Adapter:**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;


    public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);

        boolean onItemLongClick(int position);
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {


        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
            itemView.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(true); // vibration feedback on long click
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null)     mClickListener.onItemLongClick(getAdapterPosition());
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**And in your MainActivity implement the ItemClickListener and overwrite its methods:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements MyAdapter.ItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        //TODO Add OnClick behaviour
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(int position) {
        return false;
        //TODO Add OnLongClick behaviour
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Android guide about input Events [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html).

TLDR; You should use [OnClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) and [OnLongClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **Adapter** for this purpose, additionally you have to use **GestureDetector** for long press, **AlertDialog** for confirmation message and handle requisite **sqllite** accordingly.